# Split data frame into multiple data frames based on unique column combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

units = [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5]
locations = [30, 30, 30, 32, 32, 32]
timestamps = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
quantities = [1, 5, 3, 10, 35, 39]
data = {'units': units, 'locations': locations, 'timestamps': timestamps,
        'quantities': quantities}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

that looks like this:

```
 >>> df
   units  locations  timestamps  quantities
0      1         30           1           1
1      1         30           2           5
2      1         30           3           3
3      5         32           1          10
4      5         32           2          35
5      5         32           3          39
```

I need to get a list of data frames from all **unique combinations** of units and locations, i.e. something that uses `df.groupby(['units', 'locations'])`. The end result should look something like this:

```
(1, 30)
   timestamps  quantities
0           1           1
1           2           5
2           3           3

(5, 32)
   timestamps  quantities
3           1          10
4           2          35
5           3          39
```

is this possible, please?

Answer (score 2):

Run a dictionary comprehension through the groupby. You can read up more on this on the Pandas doc for [groupby:split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) page:

```
d = {name:group.filter(['timestamps','quantities']) 
     for name, group in df.groupby(['units','locations'])}

#print(d.keys())
#dict_keys([(1, 30), (5, 32)])

print(d[(1,30)])

    timestamps  quantities
0       1           1
1       2           5
2       3           3

 print(d[(5,32)])

  timestamps    quantities
3       1          10
4       2          35
5       3          39
```

Answer (score 1):

another method is to use dict comp with `groupby` and `concat`

```
d = pd.concat(({combo : data for combo,data in df.groupby(['units','locations'])}))

print(d)

        units  locations  timestamps  quantities
1 30 0      1         30           1           1
     1      1         30           2           5
     2      1         30           3           3
5 32 3      5         32           1          10
     4      5         32           2          35
     5      5         32           3          39
```

Answer (score 0):

you are right that it is just groupby:

```
cols = ['units','locations']
for k, d in df.drop(cols, axis=1).groupby([df[c] for c in cols]):
    print(k)
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
(1, 30)
   timestamps  quantities
0           1           1
1           2           5
2           3           3
(5, 32)
   timestamps  quantities
3           1          10
4           2          35
5           3          39
```